# How to get Gradle TestKit test project's `sourceSets`?

Tags: gradle

I'm using Gradle's TestKit and want to ensure that a plugin is adding the correct paths to `sourceSets.main.proto`.

How do I access that info?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to access the `Project` object from TestKit (and I'm suspecting it's impossible to do so).

One way to get at `sourceSets.main.proto` would be to create a task within the test data `build.gradle` file. For example:

```
        tasks.register('assertMainProtoSrcDirsIncludesProtopPath') {
          doLast {
            assert sourceSets.main.proto.srcDirs.contains(file("${rootDir}/${protop.path}"))
          }
        }
```

TestKit can then be used to call that task:

```
  @Test
  @DisplayName("`sourceSets.main.proto.srcDirs` should include `protop.path`.")
  public void sourceSetsMainProtoSrcDirsShouldIncludeProtopPath(final SoftAssertions softly) {
    final BuildResult buildResult = gradleRunner
        .withPluginClasspath()
        .withProjectDir(rootDir.toFile())
        .withArguments("--info", "--stacktrace", ":assertMainProtoSrcDirsIncludesProtopPath")
        .build();

    softly.assertThat(Objects.requireNonNull(buildResult.task(":assertMainProtoSrcDirsIncludesProtopPath")).getOutcome())
        .isEqualByComparingTo(SUCCESS);
  }
```